# Hidding shader code from the XCode OpenGL ES debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I'm thinking about releasing a bunch of GPGPU functions as a framework using OpenGL ES 2.0 for iOS devices.

When capturing an OpenGL ES frame in XCode, I can see the code of the shaders being used. Is there a way to avoid this from happening? I've tried deleting and detaching the shaders with `glDeleteShader` and `glDetachShader` after linking the OpenGL ES program, but the code is still captured.

I'm not looking for a bullet proof option (which probably doesn't exist), just something that makes getting to the code a bit more difficult than just pressing a button.

Thank you.

Comment: From whom are you trying to hide your shader code? To capture an OpenGL ES frame in Xcode, a user has to already be running your app attached to the Xcode debugger. That's not exactly easy to do in an App Store deployed app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger has to capture input from calls to `glShaderSource`, the actual shader source is never stored in VRAM after compilation. I cannot think of any way to overcome this problem directly. Calling `glShaderSource`is required because OpenGL ES does not support precompiled shader binaries.

I would recommend obfuscating the original shader code, perhaps using compile time macros, or even a script to scramble variable names etc (be carful of `attribs` and `uniforms` as they affect linkage to app code).

Here is a tool used for obfuscation/minimization of shader code. I believe it is built for WebGL so it may not work perfectly. http://glslunit.appspot.com/compiler.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll go the scrambling route then. 
BTW, in OpenGL ES, binary shaders are supported. `glShaderBinary` is included in OpenGL ES 2.0, even in iOS (there's no extension to get the compiled shader from the GPU, so it's useless).

Comment: hmm I was not aware of that. i guess it will be useless until the binary format is standardized. This decision in OpenGL confuses me. it would be far easier for drivers to parse standardized byte code then implement a glsl parser and compiler. developers could also create more consistent experience by not relying on driver compilers.